# Replacing first occurence except comments using sed

Tags: sed, command-line, text-processing

I have a text file of the form:

```
a = 1
#b = [2,3]
c = 4
d = [5,6]
e = [7,8]
```

I want to replace the pattern inside the brackets (and the brackets) with a number, but ignore matches in the comments, preferably using sed.

For files with exactly one matching line, I've used

```
sed -i "/^#/!s/\[.*\]/9/" myfile
```

How can this be modified to replace only the first match if there are more?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the correct, because changing just the first occurence.

`awk '!end && /^[^#]+ = \[/ {$3="9"; end=1}1' myfile`

- if there is not end flag and line is not beggining from `#` and match to `= [`, then change the third column and set the flag to prevent changing in next occurences.

`a = 1`

`#b = [2,3]`

`c = 4`

`d = 9`

`e = [7,8]` <--- this is not changed as you want

Comment: value of "e" is not processed from sample data.

Comment: and it shouldn't, does it? As author says _How can this be modified to replace only the first match if there are more?_
??

Comment: Thank you! This performs exactly according to what I asked in the question. However, it does not work if there is more than one character to the left of '='. Any ideas for that?

Comment: sure, I've done it - added `+` to the regexp `[^#]+`
it should work, check it please.

Answer (score 0):

This one-liner should do the job:

```
sed  '/^\s*#/!{s/\[[^]]*\]/9/}' file
```

add the `-i` option if you like to do the change in place.